# Squid3 not installing on ubuntu 17

Tags: cache, squid

Hi i am new to ubuntu and hear from some one that installing squid on ubuntu will improve my client computers browsing experience. Since i am new to ubuntu and not known too much about this OS, i decide to take help.
I run following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install squid
```

above mentioned commands executed without any error and then try to backup my configuration with

```
sudo cp /etc/squid3/squid.conf /etc/squid3/squid.conf.default
```

but following error occurs.

```
cp: cannot stat  'etc/squid3/squid.conf': no such file or directory.
Please help.
```

Comment: Typo. You need the / `/etc` not `etc`

Comment: can u please write full command syntax?

Comment: `sudo cp /etc/squid3/squid.conf /etc/squid3/squid.conf.default` you have a typo `cp: cannot stat 'etc/squid3/squid.conf'` is missing the / in front of etc. Should be  cp: cannot stat `'/etc/squid3/squid.conf'` , note the leading / I put in the error message . That is why it is best to copy paste the commands you run.

Comment: now i copy and paste "cp: cannot stat 'etc/squid3/squid.conf': No such file or directory". still not happen

Comment: dear panther can u tell from start

Answer (score 1):

The directory `etc/squid3/squid.conf` is not the same as `**/**etc/squid3/squid.conf`

Note the leading **/** in the second

So you typed `sudo etc/squid3/squid.conf /etc/squid3/squid.conf.default`

```
                  ^ Note the lack of a /
```

leading to the error

> cp: cannot stat 'etc/squid3/squid.conf': **no such file or directory**

because `etc/squid3/squid.conf` does not exist, thus **no such file or directory**

you need to type `cp **/**etc/squid3/squid.conf ...`

So you need

```
sudo etc/squid3/squid.conf /etc/squid3/squid.conf.default
```

See https://www.linux.com/blog/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix

FWIW, when posting a problem with a command, copy and paste the command you ran and the full output here. You can copy - paste form the terminal.

If the output is long, use pastebin

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit